# How do I determine if Windows animations are turned on or off in WinUI 3?

Tags: winui-3

I have a `Frame` in a navigation view that I keep active at all times because it contains a `WebView2` and I don't want it to reload. I toggle visibility on and off when I need to.
I made a custom animation that mimics the entrance animation of the other pages and it runs when the frame is "navigated to".
I noticed that when I run the app remotely the page transitions are turned off for the regular pages and my custom animation still runs.
I want my animation to behave the same as the page transitions.

How can check if animations/page transitions are disabled?

Comment: Can you post code around this problem? What do you mean by "run the app remotely"?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Like when I use remote desktop to connect to a computer and run the app there.

Comment: Animations might be disabled by the OS while rendering through remote desktop. AFAIK, there's no way to know if it's disabled or not.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding If I start the application when remoted in, the animations are disabled even when I switch to directly logging into the target machine. If I start the application on the target machine and then switch to remote, the animation stay enabled. There must be a value that WinUI3 is reading on first launch to enable/disable the animations.

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't know that behavior. Yet I'm not aware of any switch or flag around animations. Found about this `Windows.System.RemoteDesktop.InteractiveSession.IsRemote` though.

Comment: You could try to use `DwmGetWindowAttribute function` with `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED`. The `pvAttribute parameter` points to a value of type BOOL. `TRUE` to disable transitions, or `FALSE` to enable transitions.